# How do I install a USB Wifi driver on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 as a dual boot with Windows 10.  I have a TP-Link wireless adapter, model number "Archer T2U".  It works fine under Windows 10, but Ubuntu doesn't see it.  I have no idea how to install a driver for this.

I found a help message somewhere that said to go to "System> Administration> Hardware Drivers", but as far as I can tell, I have no such folders or directories on my system.  Keep in mind that I have only a couple of days experience with Ubuntu, and none with any other form of Linux. Also I have no internet connectivity on the target machine, so any files will have to be downloaded from a different computer and manually transferred to this machine.

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu with the Unity Desktop which is the default for 16.04, press the Super Key (Windows Key) on the keyboard and that will bring up the dash and then type in Hardware Drivers.  However, it is recommended that you have at least one form of networking connected like the ethernet port of your laptop so that any drivers that need to be downloaded can be downloaded.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of the command `sudo lsusb.` This will tell us whether your USB device is connected.

Answer (score 1):

The mediatek chipset from your device is not supported with generic wifi drivers. One solution I am aware of is to install the drivers from ulli-kroll repository in Github: [MT7610U driver for linux](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/mt7610u)
You will probably need to install `linux-headers-amd64` in order to install the drivers.
The process is explained and it is straightforward:

> For compiling type   `make`   in source dir
>   To install the firmware files   `sudo make installfw`
>   For install the driver use `sudo insmod mt7610u.ko`

Comment: kcdtv, after reading your post I simply obtained a different wifi adapter, and it worked right out of the box, without having to install drivers or anything.  So my problem is solved, but not by using your solution.  So really it's cheating, I guess.

Comment: Happy to know that you now have WiFi. To be exact I would say that you solved your problem but the problem isn't solved. If you have time to try and can report back I guess it could be usefull for people that may not have a second adapter or want to use this model. cheers